# Quilljs, want to highlight words entered in the editor

Tags: quill

I am using the Quilljs library: [https://github.com/quilljs/quill][1],

**What I was trying to achieve:**

When typing in the editor, I wanted to detect certain words in the editor and highlight or bold them out automatically while typing. Those words will be in a javscript array. How can I achieve that problem?

This wasn't a straight forward problem and I was having a lot of problems.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @KamilNiski any update?

Comment: @KamilNiski waiting for you